# How to check if form field is touched and empty in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to warn the user if the form field is touched and left empty. I can check if the empty field is touched with `$pristine`. But if I preload form data from `$scope`, `$pristine` doesn't work. Also, I don't want to use `required` parameter, I only want to inject warning-style with `ng-class`.

```
<div ng-class="{'has-warning': !form.name.$pristine}">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="people.name">
</div>
```

Comment: seems like what you are describing is `required` so why don't you want to use it? A css warning display won't validate the field itself

Comment: I want to validate the form with `required` but this field is not necessary and I only want to warn the user.

Answer (score 5):

There are several state properties set on the ngModel described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). You may want to consider using form.name.$dirty or form.name.$touched instead.

***edit***

Try using:

```
ng-class="{'has-warning': form.name.$touched && people.name.length === 0}"
```

Comment: Combination of `$pristine` and $empty would work but there are no $empty state.

Comment: don't forget to add an <form> enclosing tag with a name attribute.. that value should goes where RobJ put 'form'

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ngFocus:

> Specify custom behavior on focus event.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

```
<div ng-class="{'has-warning': !form.name.isValid}">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="people.name" ng-focus="form.name.isValid = people.name ? true : false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use :

```
form.name.$touched && form.name.$invalid
```

it should work